# Twilio-Simple sms Form Box

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Hi I apologize if this seems like a stupid question or if I am in the wrong section, but I am working for a startup company as their main web designer, but I was tasked with adding a simple referral code to the bottom of the page where all that is needed is where the user put their number in and they get a standard non random code outputed to their phone and if possible their number is databased and I'm just not sure where to start on this, I have followed some of their tutorials, but nothing seems to be following close to this, I have most of my experience in Javascript, CSS, and HTML and this is starting to get into some uncharted territory and I was wondering if anyone could guide me in the right way? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Hey Clay, what would be your plan to solve this problem? Are you stuck in making the calls to Twilio's API?

Comment: Hey, would love to help. What have you tried so far?